# ts-jest TypeError: array.findLast is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a react component written in typescript that I am testing using `jest` and `ts-jest`. This is not an application created with `create-react-app` or `create-next-app`, this is a stand-alone component.

One of the tests involves clicking a button that runs a function with the line `array.findLast(...)`. This test always fails with: `TypeError: array.findLast is not a function`.

I can use `array.findLast()` without errors in the code and it executes as expected.

I am running the latest available versions, so I suspect the error must be in the configuration. Since I can use it in code, I hoped that telling `ts-jest` to use my `tsconfig.json` would work. It did not.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "importHelpers": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/esm",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

And finally, `jest.config.ts`:

```
import type { Config } from "jest";

const config: Config = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": ["ts-jest", { tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }],
  },
  testRegex: "(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  fakeTimers: { enableGlobally: true },
};

export default config;
```

Note that I have tried to use `preset: "ts-jest"` and remove the `transform`, but it still didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: https://node.green/#ES2023-features-Array-find-from-last

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. I was under the impression this was a standard feature already. Also didn't know about that resource.